# Hiding status bar with modal transition shows white background

Tags: ios, hidden, status

Is there a way to avoid the white background of the status bar when hiding it?

When I hide it to display a full-screen modal view (with a navigation bar) the status bar fades from black to white, just prior to the modal view appearing.

I find this distracting. I would like to have the status bar simply remain, while the modal view moves into place. At the very least it would be nice to have it fade to black instead.

And so, I can hide the status bar just fine, and display a modal view without the status bar. I just don't want the fade to occur before the modal view is in place.

I managed to hide the status bar when displaying a modal view, and can do so programmatically using:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                            withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

Or setting "full screen" in Interface Builder. I can make the status bar re-appear by calling this method with "NO" in viewWillDisappear. It workings fine.

I also had to set "Status bar initially hidden" in the plist, then set it to not hidden with the above call set to "NO" when the app loads.

Any idea on how to do this? Thanks.

UPDATE: I found that I can hide the status bar after the modal view appears using an animation as follows:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^(void)
     {
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
     }];
```

This is less annoying but now the status bar fades when the modal view is in place and is still not ideal. I hope to show the modal view over the status bar. Actually, viewing it a few more times it doesn't look bad and may even look cool :-)